# Entity Relationship Diagram - Hotel

Tags: sql, database, entity, entity-relationship, erd

I am creating an ERD for a hotel and i am new to relational databases. I am struggling with the relations and where to link entities. Here is my rough erd so far: [Link to image for ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR2cX.png)

The questions that are on my mind are:

- How is room services charged to bill via room?
- Do I need the availability entity?
- Should I link the room or booking to the bill instead of guests?
- Would the bar services be straight to the receipt or bill?
- Should I add roomType to the booking entity?

Here is the description given:

Preliminary investigation of the requirements for the system has elicited the following facts:

- Rooms are numbered from 101 to 359 (although there are only 20 rooms in all, they are over 3 floors)
- Some rooms are accessible for wheelchair users and others are not
- Rooms are of three types:

1. Single – charged at £40 per night
2. Double - charged at £52 per night
3. Suite (suitable for a family of four) – charged at £95 per night
   •

Customers are charged for a room, at a standard rate, although a record is kept on the number of people in the room

Customers are given a unique ‘customer ID’ and their information is currently kept in a card index

Customers can order specific items which can be charged to their room as extras on their bill. These charged at a standard rates as follows:

- Traditional breakfast – charged at £10
- Continental breakfast – charged at £5
- Evening meal - charged at £25 per person
- Range of bar snacks – charged at £15
- Room service meal – charged at £30

Customers can buy other items, such as drinks from the bar, but these are paid for individually and not charged to the customer’s room.
The Sunshine Coast Hotel currently use pre-printed stationery and the reception staff write out invoices for customers when they leave.

Comment: How is room service joined to room?

Comment: Do you have a description of the requirements?  How it is worded will help understand the need.  "for a hotel" is quite vague, and could go many directions.

Comment: I have added the description requirements given. And in the description it says room services are charged to the room but i wouldve said its to the guest so i dont know

Comment: @Nic3500 do you think it looks fairly ok compared to the requirements

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I noticed:

- FloorNumber is set twice.  In roomType and room.  It should not be set in roomType.
- Why put BookingID FK in the room?  The booking entry is linked to the room via the availability table.  A booking is not an attribute of a room.
- roomType does not need the RoomNumber FK.  The room as a type.  The type does not have a room.
- So for your FK, ask yourself which object has which other one?  They should not be set both ways.

The majority of your ERD makes sense, altough roomServices is not in the right place.  If you related it directly with the room like you did, how will you know guest no1 on that date in that room ordered something?  roomServices
should be linked to the bill, like you did for barServices.  This way when you produce the bill, you have:

- the booking details
- the barServices
- the roomServices

I would build roomServices with a room FK and link it to the bill via a receipt like barServices.  Also do not forget that your roomServices have a type, with different prices.  So another table roomServicesType.  roomService describes one order for 1 type of service.

The way I go about is is:

- define my objects (i.e. tables).  These must represent 1, and only 1, element in the problem.
- define my links (i.e. relations).  Depending on the type of relation (1-1, 1-n, m-n) I use a FK or a link table (I do not remember the computer science official name, but like what you did with availability).
- then I define each attribute my objects have (i.e. rows in the tables).  This is when I make sure an attribute is never defined in more than 1 table.
- then I try a couple queries in my mind.  Like: the guest is leaving, how do I know what he must be billed for?  The guest orders an evening meal, I do I record it? ...